# Cumulative sum in SQL using window function

Tags: sql, sql-server

| QTY | STOCK | RNK | ID KEY | CUM SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 35 | 1 | 1 | 35 |
| 20 | 35 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 15 | 35 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 58 | 35 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 18 | 35 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 40 | 35 | 1 | 2 | 35 |
| 20 | 35 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 15 | 35 | 3 | 2 | 0 |

CUM SUM should be MIN(QTY, STOCK-SUM(all rows in cumsum before the current row)) for every other row and for 1st row it should be MIN(QTY, STOCK-SUM(0))=> MIN(QTY,STOCK)

| QTY | STOCK | RNK | ID KEY | CUM SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 35 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 20 | 35 | 2 | 1 | -10 |
| 15 | 35 | 3 | 1 | -30 |
| 58 | 35 | 4 | 1 | -7 |
| 18 | 35 | 5 | 1 | -24 |
| 40 | 35 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 20 | 35 | 2 | 2 | -10 |
| 15 | 35 | 3 | 2 | -30 |

After, I tried I am getting the above output

```
SELECT sum(qty-stock) over (
         partition by ID KEY
         ORDER BY rnk 
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) as CUM SUM
FROM TABLE
```

Need to get correct cumsum value using a window function in the existing table

Comment: It's important to include your dbms in the question tags because SQL syntax varies by vendor and version. I added "SQL-Server"  Please [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71763797/edit) if that's not corrected.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a rolling `SUM()` here, using `SUM()` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *, SUM(QTY - STOCK) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_KEY ORDER BY RNK) AS CUM_SUM
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID_KEY, RNK;
```

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would be wise: it's more efficient, and in the case of `RNK` having duplicates it's also more accurate. It's also unclear what you have gained over the code which OP posted, is there a difference (maybe I'm missing something?)

Comment: That is beyond my pay grade, I'm not an expert in SQL.  I will research your comment.

Comment: See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/window-functions-in-sql-server-part-3-questions-of-performance/. The default window fram is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` which is subtly different and not what most people expect

Comment: I am now wondering whether this holds true on all databases, or only SQL Server.

Comment: AFAIK that is standard for ANSI SQL so I would imagine it's true for all. It's true for [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html), [Oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions#windowing_clause), [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#important)

Comment: No no...not `RANGE` being the default, whether explicitly using `ROWS` would gain any performance advantage on other databases.

Comment: CUM SUM should be MIN(QTY, STOCK-SUM(all rows in cumsum before the current row)) for every other row and for 1st row it should be MIN(QTY, STOCK-SUM(0))=> MIN(QTY,STOCK)  .... this condition is not being satisfied